# Error While MongoDump for Mongo running in docker

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodump

I have mongoDB running in a docker on a GCP instance. My main application is able to read and write with no problem. I also have a backup script which uses `mongoDump`  command. The backup scripts fails after running for sometime with following error. Moreover the script successfully runs sometimes.

```
read: connection reset by peer / Mux ending but selectCases still open 4
```

Current MongoDump command

```
docker run --rm -v /var/tmp:/workdir/ -w /workdir/ mongo:4.0 mongodump -h ${mongoHostProd} -d ${dbName} -u ${username} -p ${password} --gzip --archive=/workdir/${filename}`
```

Any recommendation on possible root cause for this.

Since the backup script runs sometimes and fails sometimes, not clear on what's the issue

Comment: Does this [MongoDB Developer Community discussion](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/mongodump-randomly-throwing-cursornotfound/2640/4) help?